# Navigation Bar Spacer Not Correctly Positioned

Tags: css

I am having a problem getting spacing correct on a navigation menu. I have created a image seperator for my top and bottom menu. Problem is I cant get the links to center vertically on the page.

Currently under #footer li I have a top-margin:-16px; . That is the only thing that hold the spacer in the place that I want it in. If it is removed the links go to the correct position but the spacer drops way below the footer. Any ideas on what I can do to make the links center vertically on the footer as well as keep the spacer in its current place.

Here is a link the the site: http://www.opelikaschools.org/sandbox/jupgrade/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add padding-top property for CSS rule "#footer li"

Comment: That did it! I figured it would be something easy!